# How do I get GUID of apps installed from Microsoft Store?

Tags: windows-store, guid

I have installed Ubuntu app from Microsoft Store on Windows 10 1903. For some reasons I want to know its GUID. How can I get that, may be using some command on CMD or Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Navigate to the [Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/windows).
- Enter the name of the app in the search bar.
- Copy the app id from URL. The app id for Ubuntu is *9nblggh4msv6*.
- Now open `https://bspmts.mp.microsoft.com/v1/public/catalog/Retail/Products/<app id>/applockerdata` after replacing the `<app id>` with the app id of the application.
- The page's content will look like this:

  ```
  {
    "packageFamilyName": "CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc",
    "packageIdentityName": "CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows",
    "windowsPhoneLegacyId": "ba50f801-2d96-4517-a737-575f32f0fb61",
    "publisherCertificateName": "CN=23596F84-C3EA-4CD8-A7DF-550DCE37BCD0"
  }
  ```

  The *windowsPhoneLegacyId* is the required GUID.

#### Credits: [Examples of obtaining Windows app IDs manually - IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS8H2S/com.ibm.mc.doc/winphone_enrollment_source/concepts/appid_manual_steps.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on above answer as not enough points...so to add more help for folks who use a different version of Ubuntu, specifically on 20.04 LTS. I found the URL by Sharing it in the Windows Store app on my computer (I suppose website may have been a better choice) and select copy url option to get the new app id (9n6svws3rx71) and then used the same url as mentioned by Kulfy to get to https://bspmts.mp.microsoft.com/v1/public/catalog/Retail/Products/9n6svws3rx71/applockerdata
The content looks like:

```
{   
"packageFamilyName": "CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc",
"packageIdentityName": "CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows",  
"windowsPhoneLegacyId": "ca5e8315-170a-4dea-8d85-92ace76427bb",   
"publisherCertificateName": "CN=23596F84-C3EA-4CD8-A7DF-550DCE37BCD0" 
}
```