# How do I add application on Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-10, windows-terminal

I have installed [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N0DX20HK701) and [Ubuntu App](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6) from Microsoft Store. According to the description of the app,

> The Windows Terminal is a new, modern, fast, efficient, powerful, and productive terminal application for users of command-line tools and shells like Command Prompt, PowerShell, and WSL.

To use WSL, I need to launch Ubuntu in Windows Terminal, but I can't find the option for that.

[image: Screenshot]

How do I add Ubuntu in the menu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Click on Settings.

  [image: Screenshot]
- Choose a text editor to edit that .json file.
- Find `profiles` entry and add this after the CMD entry putting a comma (,) after `}` to separate the entries.

  ```
  {
      "acrylicOpacity" : 0.75,
      "closeOnExit" : true,
      "colorScheme" : "Campbell",
      "commandline" : "ubuntu",
      "cursorColor" : "#FFFFFF",
      "cursorShape" : "bar",
      "fontFace" : "Consolas",
      "fontSize" : 10,
      "guid" : "{GUID of the app in double quotes}",
      "historySize" : 9001,
      "icon" : "Absolute path of icon (with double quotes)",
      "name" : "Ubuntu",
      "padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0",
      "snapOnInput" : true,
      "startingDirectory" : "%USERPROFILE%",
      "useAcrylic" : true
  }
  ```
- Note that the GUID must be inside `{` `}`.
- Save the file. Click on drop-down menu again to check if it has been added.

  [image: Screenshot 2]

**Notes:**

1. To get the GUID of an app, see this question: [How do I get GUID of apps installed from Microsoft Store?](https://superuser.com/q/1455847/1049284)
2. You can download the logo in png format from anywhere of x48. I've used [this icon](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/3166/ubuntu-logo_icon) and 48x48 size.