# What is the series of letters and numbers in winget Microsoft packages ID?

Tags: windows-10

When I run `winget list` on Windows 10, I get the following output (in French, but the important column is `ID`):

```
Nom                                            ID                                                  Version            Disponible Source
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
Messages Microsoft                             Microsoft.Messaging_8wekyb3d8bbwe                   4.1901.10241.1000
Visionneuse 3D                                 Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer_8wekyb3d8bbwe           7.2107.7012.0
Microsoft Edge                                 Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge.Stable_8wekyb3d8bbwe        98.0.1108.50
...
Python 3                                       Python.Python.3                                     3.9.2150.0         3.10.2150… winget
```

As you can see, Microsoft packages have a series of letters and numbers in their ID (`8wekyb3d8bbwe` in this example). What does this refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`8wekyb3d8bbwe` is the **Publisher ID** for Microsoft.

You can see more detail if you run the **Get-AppXPackage** PowerShell cmdlet.

These IDs should align with Microsoft Store publishers, and should be unique per publisher.

Answer (score 1):

The string `8wekyb3d8bbwe` is a random string chosen by Microsoft to
differentiate the names of its applications from user applications.
It has no other purpose except avoiding conflicts with user IDs.
Some Microsoft employee seems to have had some fun with the
keyboard while inventing it.

You will see this string repeated for all the applications
in the Microsoft applications list at
[Package names for apps provisioned in Windows 10, version 1709](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/remove-provisioned-apps-during-update#package-names-for-apps-provisioned-in-windows-10-version-1709).

The origin of this string is unknown and unexplained by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Winget supports packages from 2 sources - its 'own' repositories, and the windows store. For windows store apps, the [apps have a guid](https://superuser.com/questions/1455847/how-do-i-get-guid-of-apps-installed-from-microsoft-store), and in a sense, I suspect this was for ease of having the 'same' package for 'different' formats, and that the windows store seems to be an extension of a windows phone appstore.

Interestingly there seem to be 3 different formats (or more?) in winget, and package names seem arbitrary.

```
Xbox Game Speech Window                                                                            Microsoft.XboxSpeechToTextOverlay_8wekyb3d8bbwe      1.21.13002.0
Microsoft Teams                                                                                    MicrosoftTeams_8wekyb3d8bbwe                         22006.600.1133.7409
Windows Web Experience Pack                                                                        MicrosoftWindows.Client.WebExperience_cw5n1h2txyewy  421.20070.45.0
```

Microsoft uses Microsoft.ProductName_DevID - *except for MSteams* MS seems to use 2 different developer IDs as well.8wekyb3d8bbwe for most things but the web experience pack is under

Except when they don't

```
Microsoft Edge                                                                                     Microsoft.Edge                                       98.0.1108.50                         winget
Microsoft 365 - en-us                                                                              O365HomePremRetail - en-us                           16.0.14827.20192
```

Admittedly these are not store apps but would some *consistancy* hurt? Edge uses Microsoft as the devid, edge as the product id. O365 has no dev id only a product id

```
7-Zip                                                                                              7zip.7zip                                            19.00                      21.07     winget
```

7zip here is a winget application and uses a developer.product ID
Applications on a winget repository tend to have a 'simpler' publisher.name.(version?). Here it's 7zip for both.

the winget list command *also* shows software installed in other ways

```
Quake II                                                                                           Steam App 2320                                       Unknown
Windows Driver Package - Google, Inc. (WinUSB) AndroidUsbDeviceClass  (08/28/2014 11.0.0000.00000) 092555911492C6959D2596D612F52DCA71881CA2             08/28/2014 11.0.0000.00000
Cyberpunk 2077                                                                                     1423049311_is1                                       1.31
Epson Customer Research Participation                                                              {B26449A6-6007-4460-B4FE-C4776115BCEA}               1.83.0000
NVIDIA Graphics Driver 511.65                                                                      {B2FE1952-0186-46C3-BAEC-A80AA35AC5B8}_Display.Driv… 511.65
```

Yes, its a mix of random GUIDs, assorted identifiers and .... whatever people feel like naming it.

Looking at all that - the  series of letters and numbers  in a package name don't have any 'real' meaning. They're GUIDs, version numbers and package names used by the various data sources winget is calling on. Any real meaning is going to depends on the context of how the program is installed, and how the developer chooses to release it

Comment: You might want to update your answer to indicate the publisher ID is added onto the package name.

Comment: The other answers seem to cover it for Ms/windows store. I might swap out 7zip for something else without a publisher and app name identical. It's just so inconsistent ._.